# Kernel dying repeatedly whenevr I try to import Geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

I am trying to import geopandas into my jupyter notebook but kernel keeps dying.  I am pretty new geopandas and jupyter notebooks too.

I have tried to update both jupyter notebooks and geopandas.

"import geopandas"

I get an error "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."[Kernel dying error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLkZ4.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried running this outside of the jupyter environment, say, in a shell?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I tried to run it in the shell and it still didn't  work.

Comment: Can you show the error message if you run it in a shell? And can you also try to do `import fiona` (one of the dependencies of geopandas) Can you also explain how you installed geopandas? (it seems you are using Anaconda, but did install it with pip instead of conda?)

Comment: You are right I am using Anaconda and I installed it using the "conda install pandas". I tried to import fiona but the kernel still dies. I have tried to install/update both fiona and geopandas but that doesn't seem to work too. I used the Anaconda prompt to open python but when I import fiona or geopandas, it gets out of python and goes back to Anaconda (I am guessing that is how the kernel dies in the shell) but doesn't import the library.

Comment: And you don't see any error message before it dies? Can you show the output of `conda list` ?

Comment: In the shell it doesn't give any error message, it just gets out of python.                                    (base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Jul  2 2019, 02:21:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import geopandas as gpd

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>         This is how it looks

Comment: have you tried uninstalling geopandas via conda and then installing it using pip?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and discovered that my jupyter was running out of memory.

1. Try to `import fiona` before you `import geopandas`
2. Please use these extensions to check if you are not running out of memory. Try installing the jupyter-resource-usage extension to verify [https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/admin/nbresuse.html#:~:text=The%20jupyter%2Dresource%2Dusage%20extension,corner%20of%20the%20notebook%20interface.](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/RadiantMLHub/ml4eo-bootcamp-2021/HEAD%20mybinder.orgmybinder.org)
3. You can also run the notebook within binder, that should resolve any out of memory issues:
   [https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/RadiantMLHub/ml4eo-bootcamp-2021/HEAD
   mybinder.orgmybinder.org](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/RadiantMLHub/ml4eo-bootcamp-2021/HEAD%20mybinder.orgmybinder.org)

Save your notebook/folder/files to github and copy the link into the binder.

Comment: Importing fiona first solved my problem. I don't understand why but I thank you!